# How to remove search_plate in SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

[image]

I am able to change background for `SearchView` using following code:

```
    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_search_view);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)mSearchView.findViewById(mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null));
    layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.curve_stroke_border_white_bg));
```

But How to remove `search_plate` in Search view ( **which is shown as red color selected in picture**).

Can anyone have any idea please help me..

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose, this will help you

```
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
View searchPlateView = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
if (searchPlateView != null) {
    searchPlateView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //depand you can set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.activity_home_action_search); 
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

        View searchplate = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        searchplate.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
}
```